# Transactional annotation error

Tags: java, spring-boot, dependency-injection

When I put "`@Transactional(readOnly=false)`" annotation in my Service class I get the following error

Description:

> The bean 'studentService' could not be injected as a
>   '`com.student.service.StudentServiceImpl`' because it is a JDK dynamic
>   proxy that implements: com.student.service.StudentService

Sample code:

```
@Service("studentService")
@Transactional(readOnly=false)
public class StudentServiceImpl implements StudentService {

}

public interface StudentService {

}
```

Action:

> Consider injecting the bean as one of its interfaces or forcing the use of CGLib-based proxies by setting `proxyTargetClass=true` on `@EnableAsync` and/or `@EnableCaching`.
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

**What is causing this?**

Comment: If you are trying to build project using JRE then can you please change it to JDK? Do you have all aspect related jars on your classpath?

Comment: It's my mistake, I have autowired the implementation class insted of Interface.

Comment: You could answer your own question with that answer because I ran into the same thing and this helped me resolve it. Thanks!

Answer (score 26):

As SO already mentioned on the comment, the error occurs when you are trying to inject/autowire the implementation class instead of interface.

> The bean 'studentService' could not be injected as a
>   'com.student.service.StudentServiceImpl' because it is a JDK dynamic
>   proxy that implements: com.student.service.StudentService

On the setup posted by SO,

```
public class StudentServiceImpl implements StudentService {
}

public interface StudentService {
}
```

If you autowire the interface as below you won't get an error:

```
@Autowired //or @Inject
StudentService studentService;
```

Comment: If there are many implementations of interface how does the spring know which one I want to inject?

Comment: @Nurlan check Qualifier annotation

Answer (score 17):

in spring boot projects, try to add :

```
spring.aop.proxy-target-class=true
```

to your application.properties

**OR**

```
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass = true)
```

to your spring boot entry point.

Comment: Aprt from \@EnableAspectJAutoProxy, you can add proxyTargetClass = true to any of \@EnableAsync and/or \@EnableCaching

Comment: @AbhishekChatterjee This is actually better as `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy` seems to require an additional dependency. Also `@EnableCaching` can sit in a dependency so dependees can't miss it.

Answer (score 2):

In your application class file add this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableCaching(proxyTargetClass = true)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem and resolved in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61079733/9832322) way