# Spring Boot: The bean 'auditLogDao' could not be injected as a 'AuditLogDao' because it is a JDK dynamic proxy

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I am getting the following error in a Spring Boot project on which I work:

> The bean 'auditLogDao' could not be injected as a '{redactedpathwithcorporatename}.AuditLogDao' because it is a JDK dynamic proxy that implements:
>       org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository
>
> Action:
>
> Consider injecting the bean as one of its interfaces or forcing the use of CGLib-based proxies by setting proxyTargetClass=true on @EnableAsync and/or @EnableCaching.

I have tried a variety of solutions on StackOverflow without success, specifically:

1. [Checking that I am indeed calling the interface, not the implementation.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39483059/transactional-annotation-error#answer-43715808)
2. Adding @Component to the top of SwitchUserFilter
3. Changing @Resource to @Autowired.

**AuditLogDao.java**

```
public interface AuditLogDao extends JpaRepository<AuditLog, String> {}
```

**AuditLogService.java**

```
public interface AuditLogService {
    AuditLog save(final AuditLog auditLog);
}
```

**AuditLogServiceImplementation.java**

```
public class AuditLogServiceImplementation implements AuditLogService{

    @Resource private AuditLogDao auditLogDao;

    @Override
    public AuditLog save(AuditLog auditLog) {
        return auditLogDao.save(auditLog);
    }
}
```

The file where I actually want to use the service to save information

**SwitchuserFilter.java**

```
public class SwitchUserFilter
        extends org.springframework.security.web.authentication.switchuser.SwitchUserFilter {
    @Resource AuditLogService logService;
'''
        logService.save(auditLog);
'''
}
```

I am relatively new to Spring Boot, so an explanation of why it fixes the problem would be appreciated.

Comment: have you tried annotating you repository class with `@Repository` and your service implementation class with `@Service` ?

Comment: Just tried that. It did not change the error message. I added `@Service` above the class in AuditLogServiceImplementation.java and `@Repository` above the interface in `AuditLogDao.java`

Comment: Does it start without problem if you temporary comment out the `@Resource` annotation for the logService in the SwitchuserFilter class?

Comment: could you plz add your application.properties or application.yml file along with your main class and any  `@Configuration` classes... could help analyzing this issue. thx

Comment: @Selindek yes it does. It instead gives a NullPointerException. Any insight on why it runs without that?

Comment: @TommyBrettschneider it is a large project which I have not fully explored, so I will comb through the code and ping you when I can extract that stuff.

Comment: @MatthewGaiser are there any other repo beans in your app that are already wired up successfully on application startup (without this error) ? check if your app's main class, the one containing the method `public static void main(String[] args){}`, has an `@EnableJpaRepositories` type-level annotation or if some other `@Configuration` class has this annotation set... also maybe have a look at the Spring Data JPA docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.5.0.RELEASE/reference/html/repositories.html

Comment: @TommyBrettschneider probably 50+. This one is the sole one not to work.  Yes, our TransactionConfig file has the `@EnableJpaRepositories` in it. I shall take a look at that documentation.

Comment: @MatthewGaiser check if your repo is located in a different package than any of the working repos... you can add a param to this `@EnableJpaRepositories` annotation to specify in which packages Spring should "look" or (component-)scan for repository interfaces... if so, just try moving your repo to the same package as one of the other working repo interfaces to check if this get's things running ;-)

Comment: @TommyBrettschneider thanks for your help. Selindek got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the following code will solve your problem. Add it to the `AuditLogServiceImplementation` and remove the `@Resource` annotation from the auditLogDao.

```
@Autowired
private ListableBeanFactory beanFactory;

@EventListener({ContextRefreshedEvent.class})
void contextRefreshedEvent() {
    auditLogDao = beanFactory.getBean(AuditLogDao.class);
}
```

You can do a similar trick in the filter too, whatever more comfortable for you.

I don't know what is the exact problem, but it's some kind of circular-dependency-like issue. 
So by manually importing any bean which is affected in this loop, you can resolve the loop. You will set this one particular dependency AFTER Spring had created all of the other beans.

Comment: And this made it go! Thanks.