# How to fix @Transactional annotation issues while configuring Hikari connection pool?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-transactions

I am facing the below issue when I have my service implementation class annotated with @Transactional

````
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

The bean 'BusinessServiceImpl ' could not be injected as a 'com.business.service.BusinessServiceImpl ' because it is a JDK dynamic proxy that implements:
    com.business.service.BusinessService


Action:

Consider injecting the bean as one of its interfaces or forcing the use of CGLib-based proxies by setting proxyTargetClass=true on @EnableAsync and/or @EnableCaching.```

Transactional and Hikari Connection pool configuration:
````

```
 @Configuration
 @EnableTransactionManagement
 public class HibernateConfiguration {

@Autowired
private Environment environment;

@Bean
public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
    LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
    sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan("com.business.model");
    sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
    return sessionFactory;
 }

@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    HikariDataSource dataSource = new HikariDataSource();
    dataSource.setPoolName("ConnectionPool");
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.driverClassName"));
    dataSource.setJdbcUrl(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.url"));
    dataSource.setUsername(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.username"));
    dataSource.setPassword(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.password"));
    dataSource.setMaximumPoolSize(20);
    dataSource.setConnectionTimeout(TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(10)); // default is 30000
    dataSource.setInitializationFailFast(true);
    dataSource.setIdleTimeout(TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(10));
    dataSource.setMinimumIdle(3);
    dataSource.setMaxLifetime(TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(15));
    dataSource.setIdleTimeout(TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(10));
    // Following two properties for monitoring purpose
    dataSource.setLeakDetectionThreshold(TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(2));
    dataSource.setRegisterMbeans(true); //As we are setting this property using HikariCP, We have to disable the default Mbean exporter() method 
    return dataSource;
}

@Bean
public MBeanExporter exporter() {
    final MBeanExporter exporter = new MBeanExporter();
    exporter.setAutodetect(true);
    exporter.setExcludedBeans("dataSource");
    return exporter;
}

private Properties hibernateProperties() {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put("hibernate.dialect", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
    properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
    properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.format_sql"));
    return properties;        
}

@Bean
@Autowired
public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory s) {
    return new HibernateTransactionManager(sessionFactory().getObject());
}
    }
```

Service implementation class:

```
  @Service
  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  @Transactional
  public class BusinessServiceImpl implements BusinessService {

   @Autowired
   private EmployeeManagementDao employee;
   
   ...............
   }
```

Service Interface:

```
  public interface BusinessService {
          
       -----------
  }
```

I tried to solve the issue by taking reference from this answer:

[Transactional annotation error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39483059/transactional-annotation-error#answer-43715808)

but it did not fix my issue.

I did the same kind of autowiring for other implementation class, there it's working fine but in this class I am facing the issues.

Can someone help me here please.

Spring Boot main class:

```
  @SpringBootApplication
  @Configuration
  public class BusinessWebApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    SpringApplication.run(BusinessWebApplication .class, args);
}

@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
    setRegisterErrorPageFilter(false); 
    return application.sources(applicationClass);
}

private static Class<BusinessWebApplication> applicationClass = BusinessWebApplication .class;
  }
```

In RetailBusinessServiceImpl, I am autowiring the BusinessServiceImpl class as I need to use some of the methods which are in BusinessServiceImpl

```
   @Service
   @Transactional
   public class RetailBusinessServiceImpl implements RetailBusinessService {

   @Autowired
   private BusinessServiceImpl service;

    }
```

Service class:

```
   public interface RetailBusinessService {

}
```

Comment: Is this a maven project? do you have all the required dependencies/jars?

Comment: yea Maven project and i have added all the required dependencies like Hikari

```<!-- Hikari connection pool -->
  <dependency>
         <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
         <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
   </dependency>```

Comment: This looks like Spring Boot project. Can you show us the entry-point class?

Comment: Please, don't add dependency definitions in the comments, rather you can edit your question.

Comment: Spring boot main class added, please have a check

Comment: Can you show us the class where you are using or injecting `BusinessServiceImpl`?

Comment: I have updated the question and added the code where I am autowiring the BusinessServiceImpl, please have a check

Comment: Change `private BusinessServiceImpl service` to `private BusinessService service` in RetailBusinessServiceImpl. You need to use interface not the impl class.

Comment: But there are few inner methods in BusinessServiceImpl class which are not in the interface BusinessService . That's why I am autowiring the implementation class

Comment: I have used `spring.aop.proxy-target-class=true` in application.properties file and this resolved the issues but ow I am getting **Session is closed**  error during save operation

Comment: I don't know about your issue, but it probably is not a good idea to call the method `sessionFactory()` in `transactionManager()` as this might give you a second sessionFactory in addition to the one that is defined as a bean. Simply add it as a parameter of `transactionManager()` and you should be sure to use the same instance.